# Show that if $n^3-7n^2 + n$ is an odd number then n is an odd number.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Need tips on how to think on solving the question:

> Show that if $n^3-7n^2 + n$ is an odd number then $n$ is an odd number.

Comment: You have posted 5 questions in the course of couple of months, but you still can't format?

Comment: Try proving the contrapositive: if $n$ is even, then $n^3 - 7n^2 + n$ is even.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint.** An odd number times an odd number is an odd number; an even number times either an even number or an odd number is an even number.  So, if $n$ is odd, then

- Are $n^2$ and $n^3$ even or odd?
- What about $-7n^2$?
- What about $n^3-7n^2+n$ as a whole?

Then consider what happens if $n$ is even.  Finally, consider that as a logical rule of inference,

$$\text{"If $n^3-7n^2+n$ is an odd number then $n$ is an odd number"}$$

is equivalent to

$$\text{"If $n$ is an even number then $n^3-7m^2+n$ is an even number"}$$

(that is to say, the [contrapositive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition) of a statement is logically equivalent to that statement).  Can you put the pieces together into the desired demonstration?

Comment: You are answering the converse of the question, in the beginning.  Starting with "if n is odd", to prove that $n^3-7n^2+ n$ is odd is proving the converse.

Comment: @amWhy: It may seem that way from the start of my explanation, but note that I also ask OP to look at what happens if $n$ is even.  In the end, they will have more pieces than they need, but that's why this is just a hint, and not a directed approach.

Comment: I said that is indeed relevant, and perfectly correct.  Oops I meant everything **above** isn't relevant to the direction of the implication.  I apologize for typing my second comment too quickly, and will delete it.  So you're suggesting "If n is odd, then 2

Comment: @amWhy: That was a conscious pedagogical decision.  Of course you're free to disagree with it, and I see why you feel the way you do, but I think it will ultimately help the OP and other readers to see the entire situation, and understand why only part of it is logically connected to the desired conclusion.

Comment: So you are saying, essentially, that it is pedagogically sound, when trying to prove that $p\to q$, you first prove $q \to p$ is true (irrelevant to proving $p\to q$,) and then prove $\lnot q \to \lnot p$?  I would think it is far less cumbersome to either prove $p\to q$ directly, or else prove \lnot  q\to \lnot p$, by contrapositive?

Answer (score 3):

Proof by cases:

Since $n$ is an integer, $n$ can be either even or odd.

If $n$ is even, then $(even)^3-7(even)^2+(even)$, which must produce an even result.

Since $n\ne even$ because $n^3-7n^2+n=odd$, $n$ must also be odd.

> Thus, if $n^3-7n^2+n$ produces an odd number, $n$ is also an odd number.

Answer (score 1):

Note that given:

$f(n) = n^3 - 7n^2 + n = n(n^2 - 7n + 1); \tag 1$

if $n$ is even, then $f(n)$ must be even since by (1), $n \mid f(n)$ and $2 \mid n$; therefore, $f(n)$ odd precludes the case $n$ even, so $n$ must then be odd.

So I guess the way to think about it is to observe, if possible, that the factorization of $f(n)$ given in (1) holds.

Answer (score 1):

Proof of the Contrapositive:

Assume $n$ is even.

Show that $n^3 -7n^2 +n$ is even.

Since $n$ is even: $n=2k.$

$n^3-7n^2+n =$

$ (2k)^3-7(2k)^2 +(2k)=$

$2(2^2k^3 -7\cdot 2 k^2 +k)$ , hence even.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: Shaun.Suspect someone dislikes Contrapositives.:))

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$n^3-7n^2+n=n(n-1)^2-5n(n-1)-5n.$$
Note that the first two terms are even.

Comment: Very nice, and you are indeed showing that if the $f(n)is odd, then $n$ must be odd, and not the other way around, and you leave a little thinking for the asker to finish.